# Specify a route without subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running Rails 3.0.17.
I currently have the following defined in my routes:

```
constraints :subdomain => "" do
    get 'faq'     => 'static_pages#faq'
end
```

The problem is that it allows any faq url with a subdomain (e.g. anysubdomain.mypage.com/faq)to route to the faq page when I only want the url without a subdomain (mypage.com/faq) to route to the faq page.

Any tips/insights?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`

```
constraints SubdomainConstraint.new do
  get 'faq' => 'static_pages#faq'
end
```

In your `lib/`

```
class SubdomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: I think by default the subdomain is always "www" hence the function should be def self.matches?(request)  
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'  
  end

Comment: Would you know why constraints :subdomain => "" allows all subdomains in the first place? It's really confusing when the solution (request.subdomain.blank? in self.matches?) doesn't seem to be doing anything different but solves the problem.

Comment: In newer Rails versions `matches?` has to be an instance method rather than a class method. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints